# Since when can you patent a drug class?

Tags: patentability, us20140329849

In reference to the patent: [US 2014/0329849 A1](https://www.google.com/patents/US20140329849)

Answer (score 3):

The referenced patent claims a method of treatment, not the drug class itself (which is old and known). It's a classic example of a "new use" patent.